# Why does GetType() return Object[] as the type on array, but a bad method call error says it is the type that is in the 0th element in the array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, methods, method-call, member-access-enumeration

So, I create an array, call GetType(), and I (reasonably) get the answer Object[]. If I, however, give it a bad method, I get the type of the 0th element in the error message.

Just trying to understand Powershell more -- I assume this is because Powershell is unwrapping the array in the case it doesn't find the method on the array, then also fails on the 0th array which throws the full error?

```
PS C:\Users\x> $i = @(1)
PS C:\Users\x> $i.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\Users\x> $i.HerpDerp()
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'HerpDerp'.
PS C:\Users\x> $a = @("hi")
PS C:\Users\x> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\Users\x> $a.HerpDerp()
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'HerpDerp'.
PS C:\Users\x> $m = @("hi",1)
PS C:\Users\x> $m.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\Users\x> $m.HerpDerp()
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'HerpDerp'.
```

Comment: That's because the member invocation operator will try the invocation on the contained items if the requested member isn't found on the array itself - this feature/behavior is known as [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Pretty much what you stated in the question is correct, its also explained in the Member-Access Enumeration doc: "During member-access enumeration for a method, the operator attempts to call the method on each item in the collection. If any item in the collection does does not have the specified method, the operator returns the MethodNotFound exception."

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling this was intended but I couldn't figure out how to figure out what the mechanism was named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant information is in the comments, but I think your question deserves an answer post:

What you're seeing are the effects of **[member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration)**, a convenient PowerShell feature where **accessing a member (property or method) on an *array* (list-like collection) implicitly accesses that member on *its elements, one by one***, and **returns the results as an array**, *except* if there's only *one* result, which is returned as-is;<sup>[1]</sup> e.g.:

```bash
# Even though .Year is applied to the *array*, PowerShell returns 
# the .Year property values from the two [datetime] instances that
# are the *elements* of that array; e.g., in 2023: 
#   @( 2023, 2022 )
@( (Get-Date), (Get-Date).AddYears(-1) ).Year
```

This **only works if the specified member doesn't also exist *on the array itself***, because the array's own member takes precedence; e.g.:

```bash
# Returns 3, the *array's* .Length property value (count of elements), 
# not the length of the strings stored in the array's elements.
@( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ).Length
```

This also explains why `$i.GetType()` returned the *array's* type.

---

When member-access enumeration *is* applied, the (default) **behavior differs depending on whether you access a *property* or a *method***:

- *Property* access:

  - Any array element that *doesn't have* the specified property simply *doesn't contribute to the output*; if *no* array element has such a property, the overall result is `$null`

    ```bash
    # Outputs only 2023 (for instance), because [int] 42 has no .Year property.
    @( (Get-Date), 42 ).Year
    ```

    - Note: If the property *exists* but *happens to contain `$null`*, it *is* included in the results.
      However, due to a *bug* present up to at least PowerShell 7.3.4, [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances also contribute `$null` if the property *doesn't* exist - see [GitHub issue #13752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13752)
- *Method* access:

  - If any array element *doesn't have* a method by the specified name - or if the method call results in an *exception* - a *statement-terminating error* occurs, which means that there's *no* success output, and only *one* error is reported, namely for the first element that didn't have the method / caused an exception (this explains the results of your `.HerpDerp()` calls):

    ```bash
    # !! Statement fails as a whole, because [int] (System.Int32)
    # !! doesn't have a .ToShortDateString() method.
    @( (Get-Date), 42 ).ToShortDateString()
    ```

    - Note that while you can handle / silence such an error with a [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement, you still will *not* get *partial* results from those array elements that do have the method (and didn't cause an exception).

Note that the above implies that it isn't necessarily the *first* element that triggers the statement-terminating error and if it isn't, the results from the calls on the earlier elements are in effect *discarded*.
This is somewhat problematic, given that method calls can have side effects (and possibly have no output), in which case you may need to determine after the fact what elements the method calls *were* successfully performed on.

---

<sup>[1] In doing so, member-access enumeration mimics the behavior of PowerShell's pipeline, which may be surprising. See [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) for a discussion.</sup>